# Probleme loading image

Tags: sapui5

i am showing a table of picture in the page

```
    var oTemp = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
            vAlign: "Middle",
            cells: [
                new sap.m.VBox({
                    items: [

                        new sap.m.Image({
                            src: {
                                path: "myModel>ImageLink",

                            },

                            densityAware:false,
                            decorative: false,
                         error: function(oEvent) {
                            this.setSrc(oEvent.getSource().getProperty("src"));

                            }
                        })
                    ]
                })
            ]
        });
        otable.bindItems({
            path: "myModel>/Images",
            template: oTemp
        });
```

znd in xml

```
            <m:Table id="imageTable">

                                <m:headerToolbar>
                                    <m:OverflowToolbar>
                                        <m:Title text="some text"/>
                                    </m:OverflowToolbar>
                                </m:headerToolbar>
                                <m:columns>
                                <m:Column>
                                </m:Column>
                                </m:columns>
                               </m:Table>
```

and it always enter in the error function despite in the debugger the image is l but once i open the image elsewhere the images are loaded perfectly

Comment: if an image das not exist you try to display the missing image in the error handling function. I would suggest to display a default image in the error handling function.

Comment: @Medera i tried to displayed it in the error handling function but it is not displayed either  Actually a missing image icon is displayed

Comment: the problem is that i don't get why it is not loaded... i mean  when you try to open the link in other window it works !

Comment: it may not even be an ui issue. when you try to display th images in the WebIDE environment ist may fail. But wenn you deploy the application on the gateway, and the gateway can communicate with the "image server" it might already work.

Answer (score 1):

Will this help? http://jsbin.com/xusikeh/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <script 
            src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" 
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap" 
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" 
            data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex" 
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      .sapMObjLTitle {
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    </style>

    <!-- XML-based view definition -->
    <script id="oView" type="sapui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View height="100%" controllerName="myView.Template"
      xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
      xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
      xmlns:m="sap.m">
      <m:Table id="imageTable">
        <m:headerToolbar>
          <m:OverflowToolbar>
            <m:Title text="some text" />
          </m:OverflowToolbar>
        </m:headerToolbar>
        <m:columns>
          <m:Column>
          </m:Column>
        </m:columns>
      </m:Table>
      </mvc:View>
    </script>

    <script>
      sap.ui.define([
        'jquery.sap.global',
        'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
        'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel',
        'sap/m/ColumnListItem',
        'sap/m/VBox',
        'sap/m/Image'
      ], function(jQuery, Controller, JSONModel, ColumnListItem, VBox, Image) {

        return Controller.extend("myView.Template", {
          onInit: function(oEvent) {
            var oView = this.getView();
            var oTable = oView.byId("imageTable");

            oTable.bindItems({
              path: "myModel>/Images",
              template: new ColumnListItem({
                vAlign: "Middle",
                cells: new sap.m.VBox({
                  items: new Image({
                    src: '{myModel>ImageLink}',
                    densityAware:false,
                    decorative: false
                  })
                })
              })
            });


            oView.setModel(new JSONModel({
              Images: [{
                ImageLink: "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"
              }]
            }), "myModel");
          }
        });
      });


      var oView = sap.ui.xmlview({
        viewContent: jQuery('#oView').html()
      });

      oView.placeAt('content');


    </script>

  </head>
  <body class="sapUiBody">
    <div id='content'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for you reply i tried that but it doesn't work either always showing the missing image icon :( but i think as Medera says maybe it is a problem with the image server communication